# how to setup a rule before executing update statment in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables, Course and Registration.  I need to block entry in Registration, if the number of students registered is more than 5 (the number of registered students is saved in the Course table.

Answer (score 0):

Think it will be better if you can share the table structure for the two tables.

However from the information provided, you can define a BEFORE INSERT trigger on table2. This trigger will check table1 for count of registered students.

[You can find information about triggers here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020)

Hope it Helps
Vishad